# How to add options to a select list of a content type?

Tags: nodes, hooks, forms

I built a module that creates a form and let the user to add a variable called `unit` into database. Now this `unit` should be the `options` of select list of a content type. the form id of the content type is `phone_book_node_form`, but the problem is I can't add options to the select list. this is the firebug output of the form (content type)

[image]

the name of the select list field is `field_phone_yegan`. I tried this function in `template.php`

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    switch ($form_id){
        case 'phone_book_node_form':
            $form['field_phone_yegan'] = array(
                '#options' => array('yes'=>t('yes'),'no'=>t('no'))
            );  
            break;              
    }
}
```

nut nothing was added to the select list. I also tested

```
$form['edit-field-phone-yegan-und'] = array(
                '#options' => array('yes'=>t('yes'),'no'=>t('no'))
            );  


$form['field_phone_yegan[und]'] = array(
                '#options' => array('yes'=>t('yes'),'no'=>t('no'))
            );
```

but it didn't work. How do I can add options to this content type select list?

Comment: I believe it doesn't work.... It will check for Allowed values list and results in validation error.. I would suggest create a new select field in form alter and handle CRUD operations by creating schema using install file..

Comment: @AnilSagar do you mean to tell me there is no way to add options of a list in a content type?

Comment: You can change the select list option using solution mentioned here by me.. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111117/select-menus-with-the-ability-to-insert-new-values/111121#111121 .. But if you change the existing values it will lead to error if value is not available..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like using a taxonomy would be more appropriate here. Taxonomies allow lists and terms can be automatically created from user input, in this example something like the [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module would be of use. Details from project page:

> Provides a new Forms API element which is a select/radios/checkboxes element that has an 'other' option. When 'other' is selected a textfield appears for the user to provide a custom value.

Comment: I recommend you to use https://drupal.org/project/cck_select_other

Answer (score 0):

I found it, first I should install the [cck_select_or_other module](https://drupal.org/project/cck_select_other) , it provides us two usefull textareas:

```
1. PHP Code
```

This textarea accepts php code and the php code should return an associative array which is used as options in the  field. in my case this code works :

[image]

```
2. Other
```

The second, option `Other` is automatically added in the select list and by clicking on it, a textfield appears and lets you to insert your option.